# Using JavaScript to create and append nested div elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to **use JavaScript to update the CSS layout** as the webpage loads. My code looks like so:

```
var container = 0; // Add Total UI
var containerTitle = 0; // Container Title

var article = 0; 
var articleTitle = 0;

var divName = 0; // temp variable for article id names
var divNameT = 0; // temp variable for title id names

function setLayout(id) {
    container = document.getElementById(id);

    for(var x = 0; x < 18; ++x) {
        // CREATE CONTAINER FOR ALL PANELS
        divName = "articleCon"+ x;
        article = document.createElement('div');
        article.id = divName;
        // SETUP CSS STYLE
        article.style.cssText = 'height: 205px; width: 300px; background: red; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; display: block; float: left;';

        setNewsTitle(count,divName); // Function Call to set Title Panel

        container.appendChild(article);
    }
}

function setNewsTitle(count,id) {
    containerTitle = document.getElementById(id);
    // CREATE CONTAINER FOR TITLE
    divNameT = "articleTitle"+ count;
    articleTitle = document.createElement('div');
    articleTitle.id = divNameT;
    // SETUP CSS STYLE
    articleTitle.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; height: 45px; width: 100px; background: yellow; display: inline;';

    containerTitle.appendChild(articleTitle);
}
```

When I compile my code without making the call to **function setNewsTitle(count,id)** all the CSS elements are working fine.
The issue I am facing here is whenever the function call is made, my page appears blank. Nothing displays on the screen.

I tried adding screenshots for better understanding, but i don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: Did you try firebug ? You can also try setting display to block instead of inline .. just in case

Comment: @Andy897: Yes I've tried firebug. Also did inline, inline-block and block display... none worked.

Comment: Always check your console when js isn't working.  You should find that your js is blowing up because `containerTitle` is undefined (hint: it hasn't been added to the dom yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ...

```
    container.appendChild(article);
    setNewsTitle(x,divName); // Function Call to set Title Panel
```

The article needs to be in place before `setNewsTitle` is run, since you are looking for the element by id. Also, you do not have `count`, you have `x` ...

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/o1wyae74/

Comment: Glad I could help and that the solution was simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, append child in DOM before call funtion setNewsTitle, replace count with x :

```
var container = 0; // Add Total UI
var containerTitle = 0; // Container Title

var article = 0; 
var articleTitle = 0;

var divName = 0; // temp variable for article id names
var divNameT = 0; // temp variable for title id names

function setLayout(id) {
    container = document.getElementById(id);

    for(var x = 0; x < 18; ++x) {
        // CREATE CONTAINER FOR ALL PANELS
        divName = "articleCon"+ x;
        article = document.createElement('div');
        article.id = divName;
        // SETUP CSS STYLE
        article.style.cssText = 'height: 205px; width: 300px; background: red; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; display: block; float: left;';

        container.appendChild(article);

        setNewsTitle(x,divName); // Function Call to set Title Panel

    }
}

function setNewsTitle(count,id) {
    containerTitle = document.getElementById(id);
    // CREATE CONTAINER FOR TITLE
    divNameT = "articleTitle"+ count;
    articleTitle = document.createElement('div');
    articleTitle.id = divNameT;
    // SETUP CSS STYLE
    articleTitle.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; height: 45px; width: 100px; background: yellow; display: inline;';

    containerTitle.appendChild(articleTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues in your code:

1. You have not actually added the element to the DOM yet, so when you attempt `document.getElementById` in your function `setNewsTitle()` - it won't find anything.
2. You have an error in the method call to `setNewsTitle(count,id)`.  You are passing "count", but count doesn't exist.  You need to call it as `setNewsTitle(x, divName)` but only AFTER you have made the call to `container.appendChild(article)`.

The setLayout function would end up something like this:

```
function setLayout(id) {
    container = document.getElementById(id);

    for(var x = 0; x < 18; ++x) {
        // CREATE CONTAINER FOR ALL PANELS
        divName = "articleCon"+ x;
        article = document.createElement('div');
        article.id = divName;
        // SETUP CSS STYLE
        article.style.cssText = 'height: 205px; width: 300px; background: red; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; display: block; float: left;';

        // Add it to the DOM first
        container.appendChild(article);
        // need to pass "X", not count
        setNewsTitle(x,divName); // Function Call to set Title Panel
    }
}
```